# Is it possible to get a salt for a (md5)hash provided we know substring of the (md5)hash without brute-forcing?

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5, brute-force

I have the starting 6 characters of a hash e.g. *48bf5c* 

And I do know that my salt is of format : "watch__bisqwit__" + randomString (of length 7 -25)

I want to find a randomString such that hash generated will have the same starting characters.

**My brute-forcing solution**: 
So for above starting 6chars (48bf5c), I will get hash as 48bf5c2260fb658b4eb389026831ad23 (not really useful for the problem) and salt as watch__bisqwit__2EZrgDzAkYdKHR1HP5tn (need to use this).

My brute forcing solution takes about 5-10 mins to get me to the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about development but known attacks against a cryptographic construct.  As such, it belongs on crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Apologies. Didn't realise this was off topic.

Comment: Sorry, you found a hash that produced the hash value that matches the 6 initial characters already it seems, so *what is your actual question*? You want to find a full hash value instead?

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica Apologies for not making it clear. I have starting 6 chars of the hash and need to find salt from it (finding entire hash is not really required to solve my problem).

Comment: Simply loop over possible salt values until you find one, with only 24 bits you only need a "counter" of approximately the same size. Obviously you could use a salt of just digits, as 10^25 is much larger than 2^24.